# libgfortran.so.1: cannot open shared object file

Tags: linux, scipy, scikit-learn, ipython, linux-mint

I am very new to installing my own programs and packages on linux, so please be gentle ;)

I am working on Linux Mint 17.3 (Rosa) 64 bit (Ubuntu Trusty) and am trying to run through the scikitlearn tutorials located here:

https://github.com/savarin/pyconuk-introtutorial

I have installed all the relevant packages using:

```
pip install numpy pandas sklearn ipython
```

and everything looks great until I start trying to import some things from related packages i.e.

```
from scipy.stats import mode
```

I see the following error code:

```
sam@samputer ~/Desktop $ ipython

In [1]: from scipy.stats import mode
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call     last)
<ipython-input-1-a8b1ace850b6> in <module>()
----> 1 from scipy.stats import mode

/home/sam/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py in <module>()
336 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
337 
--> 338 from .stats import *
339 from .distributions import *
340 from .morestats import *

/home/sam/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py in <module>()
178 from scipy._lib.six import callable, string_types
179 from numpy import array, asarray, ma, zeros
--> 180 import scipy.special as special
181 import scipy.linalg as linalg
182 import numpy as np

/home/sam/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py in <module>()
625 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
626 
--> 627 from ._ufuncs import *
628 
629 from .basic import *
ImportError: libgfortran.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm also running into issues when I try to link through to R for visualisation. I add this as it may shed further light on the issue:

```
In [11]: %%R
   ....: library(ggplot2)
   ....: 
/home/sam/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects    /functions.py:106: UserWarning: Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no     package called ‘ggplot2’

  res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)

 Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
```

If anyone can help me understand these issues and offer me some lines/links to fix them, I would be extremely grateful, as my googling hasn't made much progress.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Anaconda you should try installing packges with `conda install` first rather than `pip install` if you can — actually all of the the packages you installed come with the standard Anaconda distribution, so I would try reinstalling this first (did you install miniconda?)

For your second question I'm guessing you'll need to install ggplot in R, I think you do this by running `install.packages("ggplot2")` in R.

Comment: Hi Maxymoo!

I got rid of the packages and reinstalled using conda *consistently* and everything now works. I guess crossing pip and conda can give unexpected results ;)

Thanks for the solution!

Sam

Comment: no worries, actually pip is usually ok too but make sure you're using `anaconda/bin/pip` and not from some other installation